# py.test change order of test inside the test class

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation, pytest

I would like to change the order of test execution inside the test class when using @pytest.mark.parametrize fixture.

For example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", ['test1', 'test2'])
class TestForTesting:
    def test_1(self, param):
        print param
    def test_2(self, param):
        print param
```

In this care py.test will run:
test_1 with 'test1', 'test2' parameters and after that test_2 with 'test1', 'test2' parameters.

What I would like to do is to have it running in following order:
test_1 with parameter 'test1' and then test_2 with parameter 'test1' and after that test_1 with parameter 'test2' and then test_2 with parameter 'test2'.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the order matter? Your tests should be independent.

Comment: Sometimes I want to have a "context', so it might be convenient to run test in the specific order using the parametrize fixture.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `parametrize` at all but the "good old" way instead, then you get the order that you want in this case:

```
class BaseTest:
    def test_1(self):
        print self.param
    def test_2(self):
        print self.param

class TestX(BaseTest):
    param = "A"

class TestY(BaseTest):
    param = "B"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It can be a solution. Truly I like the parametrize fixture, I think it's the only disadvantage that I have seen so far.